# Why doesn't select2 container show in view source?

Tags: jquery-select2, inspector, view-source

Trying to understand how this "select2" Jquery plugin works.

I know it hides the regular select element and add it's own elements to provide some kind of a dropdown with search experience and when using "inspect element" i see the select2 container and all the other elements but when using view source i don't.

Can some one explain why is it? (Hoping to learn something new :)

Does view source shows only elements that was loaded on the first page load?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so my guess was in the right direction:

> View Source shows you only the HTML it received from the server's
>   response. Your JS changes happen afterward.
>
> Firebug and Chrome's debugger show you the source dynamically so you
>   can see the DOM and HTML as it has been changed. But view source will
>   only ever show you what the browser received from the server.
>   (Matt Pileggi - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21995770/inject-text-from-javascript-to-html-view-source?rq=1))